# Is it possible in TypeScript to declare type of the properties in an object if those are dynamically added?

Tags: typescript

I have a method like this.

```
private getStuff(data: string[]) : CertainType[] { ... }
```

I decided that it makes more sense to have the output in form of a dictionary (C#'ish) than an array. As far my google-foo tells me, I should use an object and put in stuff into it with the ID as the fields' names. So instead of:

```
const things: Thing[]; ...
things = [];
output.push(thingy);
console.log(things[3]);
```

I'm doing this:

```
const stuff: any; ...
stuff = { };
stuff[3] = stuffy;
console.log(things[3]);
```

So the signature of the method changed to this.

```
private getStuff(data: string[]) : any { ... }
```

It all works just dandy **but**. I like the semi-hard typed variables in TypeScript and coming from C# I strongly believe in avoiding a lot of issues by being (seemingly) nit-picky in advance (without getting within range of PO. of course).

Since the number of properties isn't known in advance, nor are their IDs, I wonder if *any* is the closest type setting or if there's something corresponding to the syntax of C# as:

```
Dictionary<string, Thing> dicky;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an object that can be indexed by any string but all values in the object are of a certain type you need a type with an index signature.

This can be written as

```
const stuff: Record<string, Thingy> = {};
```

Or, more verbosely, but equivalent:

```
const stuff: { [index: string]: Thingy } = {};
```

Comment: Like they say in Amazing Grace: "*Oh, I was blind but now I C#*"... Perfect! I'm going refactor me some code right away.

Comment: @KonradViltersten glad to hear, don't forget to upvote and mark as answered :)

Comment: Don't be so quick with the reply, then. I was hitting "accept" but it told me to wait for 59 seconds. You are simply **too** helpful.  :)

Comment: Right, as we're waiting for the time block to accept - in the first sample you're assuming that I have a class called *Record*, right? If I don't have a specialized class for it, I **have to** use the verbose, syntax. Is that correctly understood?

Comment: @KonradViltersten no, `Record` is predefined, you can use it. They are the same thing essentially `Record<string, Thingy>` == `{ [index: string]: Thingy }`